# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup4 failing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was making a program that would collect the value of the cryptocurrency verge. This script did the trick:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/")
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
find_value=soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'text-large2'})
price=find_value.text
```

Though the issue was that the result was in USD and i lived in Australia. So what i then did was put that value in a USD to AUD converter to find my value. I tried with the following code:

```
url2="http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?
Amount="+price+"&From=USD&To=AUD"
print url2
page2=urllib2.urlopen(url2)
soup2=BeautifulSoup(page2,"html.parser")
find_value2=soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'uccResultAmount'})
print find_value2
```

The result was that i would get the right url though i would get the wrong result. Could anybody tell me where i am going wrong?Thank You

Comment: A couple of things. 1. Please switch to python3 when you still can, 2 is phasing out soon, and 2. Would you mind posting your price and expected output, so people don't have to run _all_ your code? Thanks.

Comment: These problems are often due to the information you are trying to scrape being filled in via javascript.  So it is not in the markup BS has access to.

Comment: @COOLSPEED the prices change every second so theres no absolute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to scrape the currency converter:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
def convert(**kwargs):
   url = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount={amount}&From={from_curr}&To={to_curr}".format(**kwargs)
   data = str(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
   val = map(float, re.findall("(?<=uccResultAmount'>)[\d\.]+", data))
   return val[0]

url="https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/"
page=urllib.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
find_value=soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'text-large2'})
print convert(amount = float(find_value.text), from_curr = 'USD', to_curr = 'AUD')
```

Output:

```
0.170358
```